# What is blocking the mainthread in my async function setup?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just got started with async functions and am running into mainthread block. What part of my code causes this?
Any help would be appreciated

```
//mainthread function
private void ShortestPathBetweenNodes(Node start , Node)
{
    RunDijkstraAsync(start, target);
}

async void RunDijkstraAsync(Node start, Node target)
{
    List<Node> path = new List<Node>();
    path = await DijkstrAsync(start, target);
}

async Task<List<Node>> DijkstrAsync(Node start, Node target)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //omitted function code. markedNode.previous is the List<Node> to return
            return markedNode.previous;
        });
}
```

I expected this to run async on a non-mainthread, but it blocks the mainthread regardless.

Comment: In your example, `DijkstrAsync` declares its return type as `Task<List<Node>>`, but I don't see it returning anything. Is this your actual code?

Comment: @JohnWu I omitted the part of the code unrelated to the async functions. marked.previous is the returned List<Node>

Comment: Btw. `public async void`s are fire and forget.

Comment: I don't think anything in the  code you have shown is blocking your app.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing isn't strictly "blocking" per se but rather the continuations of your `async` code (i.e. the "remainder" of the `async` method after the `await` has completed) executing [on the main thread due to Unity's custom synchronization context](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/):

> Unity does provide one important piece for us however. As you can see in the above example, our async methods will be run on the main unity thread by default. [...] it works this way because Unity has provided a default SynchronizationContext called UnitySynchronizationContext which automatically collects any async code that is queued each frame and continues running them on the main unity thread.

If you append `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to your awaited calls you should get around this behaviour - but note that this will likely interfere with your ability to use Unity APIs in your continuations.